# What does this error means and how to fix it "Error in saving to database. error is: The method or operation is not implemented"?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Those are my codes on SAVE Button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
    Dim conStr As String

    conStr = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;database=ps20150385"
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    dbCon = New MySqlConnection(conStr)
    dbCon.Open()
    ' Add record to database
    Dim productName, productCat, unitPrice As String

    productName = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
    productCat = Trim(ComboBox1.Text)
    unitPrice = Trim(TextBox3.Text)


    Dim Sql As String = "INSERT INTO products (ProductName,ProductCat,UnitPrice) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox3.Text & "')"
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or ComboBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please! insert record")
    Else
        MsgBox("Record inserted successfully.")

    End If
    Try
        DbCommand = New MySqlCommand(Sql, dbconn)
        dbread = DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. error is :" & ex.Message)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        Exit Sub

    End Try
    dbread.Close()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    ComboBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried it with a semicolon at the end of the query string?  
Also, why do you trim the inputs and then never use the variables, apart from clearing them at the end?

Comment: Please ESG can you provide here corrected codes, i am  not getting well the point.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out is  that you are using `.ExecuteReader()`on an `INSERT`cmd. `INSERT`should be executed as `.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Second thing that pops out is that you are just asking for an sql injection attack (purposeful or accidental). Instead of including `TextBox.Text` In your queries, you should use parameters. Instead of direct strings. A simple special character will break your query if you don't.

Comment: I've tried correcting '.ExecuteReader()' to '.ExecuteNonQuery()' but still occurring error. **If someone can post here corrected codes through mine, it could be more helpful**.